# i2c oled display problem with STM32F401RE Nucleo Board

Tags: stm32, i2c, display, nucleo

I have an i2c oled display with an SSD1306 driver. I want to drive this display with my nucleo card. Pin configurations are shown below.

[image]

I provided the i2c connection on the display via i2c1 on the development board. I know that the slave address is 0x3C, but I wanted to check if the display is connected. I couldn't get any address output over UART, below is the code I used for scanning.

```
    /*-[ I2C Bus Scanning ]-*/
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, StartMSG, sizeof(StartMSG), 10000);
for(i=1; i<128; i++)
{
    ret = HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, (uint16_t)(i<<1), 3, 5);
    if (ret != HAL_OK) /* No ACK Received At That Address */
    {
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, Space, sizeof(Space), 10000);
    }
    else if(ret == HAL_OK)
    {
        sprintf(Buffer, "0x%X", i);
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), 10000);
    }
}
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, EndMSG, sizeof(EndMSG), 10000); 
/*--[ Scanning Done ]--*/
```

I tried to drive the display with different sample codes, but I was not successful with the nucleo board. There is no problem with the display because I can drive it with Arduino.

I couldn't find where I went wrong, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

```
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, StartMSG, sizeof(StartMSG), 10000);
for(i=1; i<128; i++)
{
    ret = HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, (uint16_t)(i<<1), 3, 5);
    if (ret != HAL_OK) /* No ACK Received At That Address */
    {
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, Space, sizeof(Space), 10000);
    }
    else if(ret == HAL_OK)
    {
        sprintf(Buffer, "0x%X", i); HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), 10000);
    }
}
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, EndMSG, sizeof(EndMSG), 10000);
```

Comment: In other words: Use another UART for debug output?

Comment: What's the use of using another uart?